# mscomctl causes crash when I move a column

Tags: vb6

In my legacy VB6 application,
When I try to move a column in a list the application locks up with a message that the application has stopped working, Windows is collecting more information about the problem.

The details collected indicate

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\Kirsten\AppData\Local\Temp\WER3A65.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\Kirsten\AppData\Local\Temp\WER6971.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\Kirsten\AppData\Local\Temp\WER69D0.tmp.mdmp

The problem signature in the first file shows

```
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>APPCRASH</EventType>
    <Parameter0>jtJobTalk.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>58216da3</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>mscomctl.ocx</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>6.1.97.82</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>403ad117</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>c0000094</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>0000e4c5</Parameter7>
</ProblemSignatures>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the controls from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019

to solve this problem.